# ELF file format, what is `byte_get`?

Tags: c, byte, elf

In readelf implementation I saw:

```
internal->sh_name      = BYTE_GET (shdrs[i].sh_name);
#define BYTE_GET(field) byte_get (field, sizeof (field))
```

But where is `byte_get` defined?

I want to know that in order to edit the following line so it works fine instead of returning corrupted:

```
internal->sh_name      = BYTE_GET (shdrs[i].sh_name)+"TEST";
```

Answer (score 0):

`byte_get` is a function pointer declared in [elfcomm.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=binutils/elfcomm.h;hb=HEAD), and defined in elfcomm.c. It is set to `byte_get_little_endian` or `byte_get_big_endian` in [readelf.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=binutils/readelf.c;hb=3633d4fb4469f5bc4e6e1593b65c7fc93d3805bb#l21064).

Comment: But this doesn't make sense to me why this works: `filedata->string_table + internal->sh_name` we are adding 2 pointers to char* which is a bug...